# How to set Relative Layout in XAML?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am not aware with `Relative` and `Absolute` layouts in **Xamarin** Forms. I am using following code to display two images according to image and in center of the screen. How's that possible?

**My Code:**

```
    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" x:Name="bigImage"  VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="150" WidthRequest="150" 
               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0.5}"
               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Factor=0.5}"/>
        <Image Source="edit_icon.png" Margin="5" HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" 
               RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=bigImage, Type=RelativeToView, Property=Width,Factor=0.9}"
               RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=bigImage, Type=RelativeToView, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**My expected result is:**

[image]